# AndroidApp crashes when installed from the play store

Tags: android

I have an app that I have recently submitted to the play store. I had tested the .apk file and everything was working fine. On the first install (from the store) - you can login but then it crashes. Here is the stack trace I am getting from the report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.e(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.g(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.MyResultReceiver.onReceiveResult(Unknown Source)
at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable.run(ResultReceiver.java:43)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am just not real sure where to start looking. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it some kind of server result not being handled correctly? It is obviously a null ptr error, so, you aren't handling a null value properly in this InitialSearchActivity class... (I assume that is your class, and not a library or something). Care to provide some of the code from that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you used some toole (like Proguard) to obfuscate your code. 
Did you test your APK after obfuscation?

From the logs above a NullPointerException has occured in your code, you'd need to de-obfuscate your code using the key files generated by the obfuscating tool in order to find out the real place (line of code) where null pointer has been accessed.

Please Note, 
In the process of obfuscation, sometimes (human error) can cause some of the required methods to be obfuscated. Which in turn causes those methods not to be found, hence an exception (NoSuchMethod) might be raised.

Comment: OP get a `NullPointerException`, not a `NoSuchMethod`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I still wanted to point out the other problems that might occur because of obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everybody. I removed the obfuscation and rebuilt the apk, got it back in the store and its working fine now. I will spend some time getting up to speed with using proguard for the next release.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this part of the stack trace is your code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.e(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.g(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.InitialSearchActivity.a(Unknown Source)
at com.latlon.MyResultReceiver.onReceiveResult(Unknown Source)
```

Your `onReceiveResult()` method in class `MyResultReceiver` was called. That method called a method `a` in the `InitialSearchActivity` class, which called a method `g` in that class which called a method `a` in that class which called a method `e` in that class. In method `e` there was a `NullPointerException` (ie: in that method you tried to use a variable that you thought contained an object reference, but instead that variable contained `null`.

It looks like the method names have been obfuscated, so you may have to look at the code to figure out what the real method names are.

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge here. Is it possible to just remove the obfuscation? I'm assuming that on my local copy of the .apk (the one not signed for the store) is not obfuscated so thats why its working fine?

Comment: It'd depend how did you exported the unsigned apk from your project. If you're using ant build, you'd need to either comment out contents of your proguard.txt or remove the reference from ant build.xml

Comment: That depends. It could be that the obfuscation is causing the problem. It could also be that your code is broken but you didn't see the problem. You can disable the obfuscation, or you can try running the obfuscated version yourself and see if you can reproduce the problem. You may want to add some logging if you can't determine what the problem is by looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation on Proguard (which is the tool that does the code obfusciation).

It is very likely that you "over-obfusciated", which can cause issues with the deployed code.  Just like you are seeing.

You can turn off Proguard functionality by editing the "proguard-project.txt" file.  To ensure no obfusciation occurs, make sure every line in this file is commented out (by placing a hash - or # mark at the start of each line).

There is a command called `retrace` that allows you to provide unmap your obfusciation. You will need to provide some files created by proguard to get this working.

Check the docs for full explanation: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Quick fix (to eliminate Proguard) is to comment the file, so it doesn't run in the first place.